# pydantic convert to jsonable dict (not full json string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonserializer, pydantic

I'd like to use `pydantic` for handling data (bidirectionally) between an api and datastore due to it's nice support for several types I care about that are not natively json-serializable.  It has better read/validation support than the current approach, but I also need to create json-serializable `dict` objects to write out.

```
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Model(BaseModel):
    the_id: UUID

instance = Model(the_id=uuid4())
print("1: %s" % instance.dict()
print("2: %s" % instance.json()
```

prints

```
{'the_id': UUID('4108356a-556e-484b-9447-07b56a664763')}
>>> inst.json()
'{"the_id": "4108356a-556e-484b-9447-07b56a664763"}'
```

Id like the following:

```
{"the_id": "4108356a-556e-484b-9447-07b56a664763"} # eg "json-compatible" dict
```

It appears that while pydantic has all the mappings, but I can't find any usage of the serialization outside the standard `json` ~recursive encoder (`json.dumps( ... default=pydantic_encoder)`) in `pydantic/main.py`. but I'd prefer to keep to one library for both validate raw->obj (pydantic is great at this) as well as the obj->raw(dict) so that I don't have to manage multiple serialization mappings.  I suppose I could implement something similar to the `json` usage of the encoder, but this should be a common use case?

Other approaches such as `dataclasses(builtin)` + libraries such as `dataclasses_jsonschema` provide this ~serialization to `json-ready dict`, but again, hoping to use pydantic for the more robust input validation while keeping things symmetrical.

Comment: See my reply at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69740271/317460 - It's a Pydantic custom type, specific for the example of UUID

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it appears this functionality has been proposed, and (may be) favored by pydantic's author samuel colvin, as https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/951#issuecomment-552463606

which proposes adding a `simplify` parameter to `Model.dict()` to output jsonalbe data.

This code runs in a production api layer, and is exersized such that we can't use the one-line workaround suggested (just doing a full serialize (`.json()`) + full deserialize).  We implemented a custom function to do this, descending the result of `.dict()` and converting types to jsonable - hopefully the above proposed functionality is added to pydantic in the future.

Comment: This has landed since then: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict

Comment: What exactly has been added? Unfortunately, no functionality to add `dict_encoders` like `json_encoders` has been added so far.

Comment: @luckydonald I'm missing where in that doc (as of this writing) there's any mention of anything like this `simplify` parameter to `Model.dict()`.

Comment: This proposal seems to have been scrapped. They went with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75739762/2011147) instead.

Answer (score 54):

#### Pydantic 1.x (old answer)

The current version of `pydantic` does not support creating jsonable `dict` straightforwardly. But you can use the following trick:

*Note: This is a suboptimal solution*

```
class Model(BaseModel):
    the_id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)

print(json.loads(Model().json()))
```

```
{'the_id': '4c94e7bc-78fe-48ea-8c3b-83c180437774'}
```

Or more efficiently by means of [orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson)

```
orjson.loads(Model().json())
```

#### Pydantic 2

There is the [`model_dump()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/root_model/#pydantic.root_model.RootModel.model_dump) method accepting the `mode` parameter.

```
mode: Literal['json', 'python'] | str = 'python'
```

> If mode is 'json', the dictionary will only contain JSON serializable types.
>
> If mode is 'python', the dictionary may contain any  Python objects.

```
class Model(BaseModel):
    the_id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)

print(Model().model_dump(mode='json'))
# {'the_id': '4c94e7bc-78fe-48ea-8c3b-83c180437774'}
```

Comment: it looks like @samuelcolvin is considering adding a `simplify` arg to `dict()` or similar https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/951#issuecomment-552463606; as this was proposed by the pydantic author, I'm hoping there is progress, but haven't finished digging through github yet

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but paying for a full round trip of serialization/deserialization can't be considered for a production environment.  For the moment we've implemented a custom workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't call it trick. It's rather something even more ugly than `a = True\n if len(str(a)) == 4: ..."

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, really don't get why the pydantic docs are so verbose. They tell you everything but what you want to know.

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative is to use the `jsonable_encoder` method from `fastapi` if you're using that already: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/

The code seems pretty self-contained so you could copy paste it if the license allows it.

Comment: and what is the difference between `jsonable_encoder` and `model_dump_json`?

Comment: Good question! my answer was for pre v2. I haven't used Pydantic in a while so I'm not sure how this compares, hopefully someone else chimes in!

Answer (score 10):

The official method in [Pydantic 2](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2-final/) is using the `.model_dump()` method with `mode="json"` argument:

```
print(instance.model_dump(mode="json"))
```

From the [`Pydantic 2 Plan`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/blog/pydantic-v2/) document:

> ```
> def model_dump_json(self, ...) -> str:
>    """
>    previously `json()`, arguments as above
>    effectively equivalent to `json.dump(self.model_dump(..., mode='json'))`,
>    but more performant
>    """
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As of 18/10/2023, `.model_dump()` will return a dictionary of the model. `.dict()` is depreciated.